# Three state conversion on query in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

If I had a boolean field in a table I would use `IIF()` ( *should stand for Incredible-IF (:* ) function to convert boolean values to desired results like

```
SELECT IIF(bool_field, 'Foo', 'Bar')...
```

Now my problem is a little bit extended. I have three states: `-1`, `0` and `1`.

- `-1` means past
- `0` means current
- `1` means future

How can I convert these states on query in Access?

Comment: You can nest IIFs: `iif(state=-1, 'minus one', iif(state=0, 'zero', iif(state=1, 'one', 'something else')))` maybe that could work?

Comment: I was trying it too. OK found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to nested IIf() functions you can also use the [Switch()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx) function

```
SELECT Switch(bool_field=-1, "past", bool_field=0, "current", bool_field=1, "future") ...
```

Sometimes it can improve readability when the IIf() nesting gets too deep.

Answer (score 0):

If I nest IIF()'s it can be done.

```
SELECT (field<0, 'past', IIF(field>0, 'future', 'current')) ...
```